# waiting before do action use jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.3.2

I use jquery version 1.3.2,

I want to use event "load" for load content of a page to  "div".

I used: `$("#div1").load("page1.php");` ---> it worked.

But i want before do event "load", it waiting about times.

it same: `$("#div1").load("page1.php",{after: 5});`

please tell me how to do, thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

You can try [delay plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-delay-plugin/) or take a look to more [traditional approach](http://www.elated.com/articles/javascript-timers-with-settimeout-and-setinterval/)

Answer (score 0):

You could try to slow the server down in sending its response, e.g.

```
//sleep for 5 seconds before outputting stuff
sleep(5);
echo 'Now I\'ll talk!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Using settimeout() would be the best and easiest way through.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $("#div1").load("page1.php");
}, 5000);
```